# How can I destroy a datatable

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, datatables

I have datatable and table have ID example.

Now I need to destroy datatable and I write:

```
$('#example').dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

but I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

also this I get in console log:[image]

What is the problem here? Why  can't I destroy the datatable? How to solve this?

Comment: You probably want `$('#example').DataTable().fnDestroy();` - note the capital `D`. Using `dataTable` (with a `d`) returns a jQuery object.

Comment: yes, but now I get: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: so capital 'D' is not a problem here

Comment: Can you console.log `$('#example').dataTable()` to see if it is what we expect it to be

Comment: I get this: http://i.imgur.com/MbK13vr.png

Comment: SO is there any way to destroy table ?

Comment: "_SO is there any way to destroy table_", yes - you are doing it right - see this 1.9.x example -> **http://jsfiddle.net/fdfm04gL/** `<instance>.fnDestroy(), `, `$('#example').DataTable().fnDestroy()` or `$('#example').dataTable().fnDestroy()` - all three methods works with 1.9.x. So your problem relies elsewhere, can you reproduce the error in a fiddle? I guess you somehow manipulate the injected DOM before `fnDestroy()`

Comment: In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v1jaom3L/ I put JS code and HTML, please help

Answer (score 22):

For latest version of datatables use:

```
$('#example').DataTable().destroy();
```

Refer to this for more: https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy%28%29

For older versions use as stated by Hobo Sapiens:

```
$('#example').DataTable().fnDestroy();
```

Comment: If you get "but now I get: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" then you may be importing jquery twice.

Comment: No, both `$('#example').DataTable().fnDestroy()` and `$('#example').dataTable().fnDestroy()` works with 1.9.x

Comment: I get the same error with .destroy(); : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Comment: @davidkonrad, sir what if I use it in a modal? I have a table inside my modal and then the data is called using ajax..

Comment: @d_unknown, Ask the question and I answer it

Comment: @davidkonrad, my question is here sir.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073255/how-to-destroy-first-initialization-of-datatable-datatable-inside-a-modal

Comment: I'm using ver 1.10 and I still don't see destroy() when I console.log the dataTables object I created. I have to use .fnDestroy() to get it to work. Perhaps the API docs are not correct: "Since: 1.10"

Comment: @jjwdesign, you need to use `DataTable()` method to access `destroy()` method. If you're using `dataTable()` then you can call `dataTable().api().destroy()` instead, see [API](http://datatables.net/reference/api) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what eventually worked for me with v1.10.

```
// Define a variable for your dataTable object to use
var reportListDataTable = null;

// Then inside a function/method somewhere...

// Destroy the dataTable and empty because the columns may change!
if (reportListDataTable !== null ) {
    // for this version use fnDestroy() instead of destroy()
    reportListDataTable.fnDestroy();
    reportListDataTable = null;
    // empty in case the columns change
    $('#reportListTableId').empty();
}

// Build dataTable with ajax, columns, etc.
reportListDataTable = $('#reportListTableId').dataTable({
    //... Your dataTables code here
});
```

Comment: Even with v1.10, it still depends on whether you are using dataTable() or DataTable(). Note "capital D".

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me is destroy the dataTable on click of a insert button rather on the fetch data button. So the button that destroys the dataTable is not recreating the table. And some other function that is called from other button click creates the dataTable. 
code is simple :

Button that destroys dataTable:

```
var otable = $('#claimRecordTable').dataTable();
if (otable != null) otable.fnDestroy();
```

button that created dataTable:

```
$('#claimRecordTable').dataTable();
```