# How to destroy first initialization of datatable (DataTable inside a modal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a modal that displays a table. And I use datatable plugin so that the data is searchable and sortable. It works properly at first but when I close the modal and click other link to the same modal, it displays error. I have found solution to destroy the DataTable and I put the `destroy()` before the initialization of the datatable but then no data is displayed inside the table.. if I put it after the initialization it gave me the initialization error the second time I click the button. How am I going to solve this?

here's my code:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/group/getMember')?>",
      type: 'POST',
      data: { 'groupID': id},
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(result){
        $('#records_table tbody').empty();
        // $('#records_table').DataTable({
            // "bLengthChange": false,
            // "paging":false,
        // });
        $('.modal-header #hdrmsg').text(result[0].fname);
        var trHTML='';

         $.each(result, function (i, item) {
            trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.fname + '</td><td>' + item.mname + '</td><td>' + item.lname + '</td></tr>';
        });
        $('#records_table tbody').append(trHTML);
        $('#records_table').DataTable({
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "paging":false,
        });
        $('#records_table').DataTable().fnDestroy();

      }

  });
```

Comment: What about use destroy() when you are closing modal?

Comment: @CorwinCZ, where will I put that code? How? I already tried `$('#viewMember').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
  $('.modal-body #records_table').DataTable().fnDestroy();
});` but still the same problem occur.. it didn't destroy the datatable.

Comment: @CorwinCZ, and also when I tried modal on `hide`, the modal now can't be closed..

Comment: @d_unknown - have replaced the datatable tag with the jquery-datatables tag. The datatable tag was originally a .NET tag, now ambigous / obsolute - jQuery dataTables is (was) identified by the datatables tag, now jquery-datatables or datatables-1.10 tags.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The main reason for destroying a dataTables instance is if you want to change the initialisation options - like change `paging` and so on. Or if the table structure should be altered. None of those circumstances seems to be the case here? To answer the question, the safest way to destroy and reinitialise a table is to use the shorthand option `destroy: true` :

```
var table = $('#records_table').DataTable({
   ...
   destroy : true
});
```

To go further, I think you are doing it a little backwards.

- Why empty the table with jQuery `$('#records_table tbody').empty();` instead of `table.clear()` ?
- Why inject records with jQuery `$('#records_table tbody').append(trHTML);` instead of using `table.row.add([...])` ?

Here is a code scenario similar to the one in the question, which reinitialises the dataTable without conflicts, each time the modal is shown :

```js
var table;
$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(response) {
         var response = $.parseJSON(response.contents);

         //clear the table, if it exists
         if (table) table.clear();

         //reinitialise the dataTable   
         table = $('#records_table').DataTable({
           destroy: true,
           bLengthChange: false,
           paging: false
         });

         $.each(response, function(i, item) {
           console.log("inserting", item);
           table.row.add([
             item.name,
             item.position
           ]).draw();
         });
       }
    });
});
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/bz958dxj/**

But you really dont need to destroy the table at all, it just slows down performance :

```js
//global table object
table = $('#records_table').DataTable({
   bLengthChange: false,
   paging: false
});

$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(response) {
         var response = $.parseJSON(response.contents);

         //clear the table
         table.clear();

         //insert data 
         $.each(response, function(i, item) {
           console.log("inserting", item);
           table.row.add([
             item.name,
             item.position
           ]).draw();
         });
       }
    });
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/8mjke9ua/**

**NB**: I just `assume` we are talking about bootstrap modals, based on the reference to `.modal-header` in the question.

**NB**²: Notice the `$.parseJSON(response.contents)`, you should do it as you are doing it in the question. The only reason for this is that the examples go trough a proxy to avoid the same-origin policy.

Comment: thanks sir for this is a great help.. I haven't thought of it sir that is why I just empty the table and append the row just as what's in the ordinary html table.. Now, I understand sir.. :)