# Django JQuery datatable ajax refresh - missing sorting buttons and inactive function calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, html, datatables

I'm running Django and using JQuery and jquery-datatables-bs3 to create a table for my models. The user can add and remove table rows, which corresponds to model instances being created or deleted in the database. Each row has an "actions" column containing a clickable function call. I'm using an ajax call to refresh the table after each user modification.

**table.html** (context: {'entities': entities, 'display_fields': display_fields })

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="datatable-editable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for key in display_fields.keys %}
                <th>{{ key }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for entity in entities %}
        <tr>
            {% for key, value in entity.display_fields.items %}
                <td>{{ value }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
            <td class="actions">
                <a href="#" class="locker"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The result:
[image: Resulting table]

The table works properly. The sorting and clickable action call work fine. No problems so far. On refresh:

**update.js** (ajax call on table modification)

```
function refresh_table() {
    $.ajax({
       url: '/refresh/url/',
          success: function(data) {
            $('#datatable-editable').html(data);
          }
    });
}
```

The refresh works, the table is re-populated with data. However, once refreshed, the table is missing its header sorting buttons and the action function calls do not work anymore, even though the table's HTML is the same:

[image: Refreshed table]

**update.js** ("locker" class on click function)

```
$('.locker').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/lock/url/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'lock': true}
    })
});
```

I presume a header refresh is necessary and the update.js is not picking up the new '.locker' classes in the updated HTML, but I'm not sure how to address this. Any ideas on how to re-enable the table sorting buttons and table row function calls? Much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You use some kind of code to initialize datatables for your table using its id or class, I guess you need to do that again in your ajax success.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, my entire approach to refreshing the table data was wrong - details in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I was trying to set the table data via .html(data), the proper way to update (draw) each new table row should be like this:

```
function refresh_table() {
    // get the table:
    if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#datatable-editable' ) ) {
        table = $('#datatable-editable').DataTable();
    }
    else {
        table = $('#datatable-editable').DataTable( {
            paging: false
        } );
    }

    // ajax refresh call:
    $.ajax({
        url: '/refresh/url/',
            success: function(json) {
            // clear table data first:
            table.clear();

            // insert new row data, assuming that json.data is an array of arrays of row values:
            for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
                    table.row.add(json.data[i]).draw();

            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Example Ajax call return JSON**: {'data': ['some_id', 'some_name', 'some_status', 'some_description', 'some_action'], [...], [...],}

I found this answer really useful: [How to destroy first initialization of datatable (DataTable inside a modal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073255/how-to-destroy-first-initialization-of-datatable-datatable-inside-a-modal)